# Android/MonoDroid: Can I load a AXML file into a View?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I understand basic AXML usage such as:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
    }
```

Is there a way to combine fragments of AXML such as:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.AddView(Resource.Layout.HomePart1);
        layout.AddView(Resource.Layout.HomePart2);
        SetContentView(layout);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [LayoutInflater.Inflate](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate%28System.Int32,Android.Views.ViewGroup%29) to build a view from a resource file:

```
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePart1, null);
```